# Shell script to do 'cdo' operation on multiple Netcdf file embedded in multiple folders

Tags: shell-script, file-management

I have a directory on my Linux machine, let's name it `MYDIR`, with a number of folders labeled based on the years (1982, 1983, 1984, ..., 2022). Whithin each sub-folder, there are other folders named according to the months (01, 02, 03, ..., 12) and several NetCDF daily data inside each of these folders as well:

```
MYDIR [directory]
--1982[folder]   
----01[folder]
----02[folder]
----03[folder]
----12[folder]   
--1982[folder]
----01[folder]
----02[folder]
----12[folder]
```

I want to perform 2 operations on each file in all the folders. The operations are defined below.

```
cdo mergetime *.nc outfile.nc;
cdo ymonmean outfile.nc L4_GHRSST-SSTfnd_1982_01.nc
```

Finally, I want to save all `L4_GHRSST-SSTfnd_1982_01.nc`,  `L4_GHRSST-SSTfnd_1982_02.nc`, ...,`L4_GHRSST-SSTfnd_2022_01.nc`, ..., `L4_GHRSST-SSTfnd_2022_12.nc` in a different folder named `monmean` in `MYDIR`.
Can someone help me create a shell script which can perform the mentioned process?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting for how to format your sample input, output, and code as Code Blocks then [edit] your question to do so.

Comment: Farshid, please [edit] your question and show us the output of `tree` run from the `MYDIR` directory, and then show what the final output you expect is. That way, we can compare what you show with what our solutions can do. Also, please note that this isn't a script writing service. Please show us what you have so far, which part of this specifically is giving you problems?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150834/discussion-between-terdon-and-ed-morton).